# Django 1.7 - App 'your_app_name' does not have migrations

Tags: python, django, upgrade, django-migrations

I am trying to upgrade from Django 1.6.7 to Django 1.7.1, so I have been trying to migrate my app.

I have followed the [django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps).

I deleted the south from my installed apps.

In the migration directory, I delete the numbered migration files and the .pyc files but I kept the directory & __ init__.py file.

I then run :

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
```

I receive the following confirmation message:

```
Migrations for 'your_app_name':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model UserProfile
```

Next I run:

```
python manage.py migrate your_app_name
```

I received the following error:

```
CommandError: App 'your_app_name' does not have migrations (you cannot selectively sync unmigrated apps)
```

As per the docs, I also ran:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake your_app_name
```

I received the same error message:

```
CommandError: App 'your_app_name' does not have migrations (you cannot selectively sync unmigrated apps)
```

**Can anyone shed some light on why this will not work for me?**

Comment: does `makemigrations` created a new file in your `migrations` folder?

Comment: yes. the new file is called 0001_initial

Answer (score 31):

I noticed that only those apps that actually contain a `migrations` folder that contain a file `__init__.py` are recognized by migrations. IE having only models.py in your app is not enough.

Answer (score 16):

If you have a single app, running [migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate) without specifying the app or migration may work.

If so, the first thing to check is that your app name matched that specified in your settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS.

As pointed out in the comments, app names can be in the form [parent_app].[app_name]. In this case, migrate needs [app_name] only.

Comment: This second part may be a bit confusing to people that land here, because the installed app name may be '[parent_app].[app_name]' whereas the migrate.py command will just want [app_name]. Confusing that can give the same error as the original poster.

Comment: THANK YOU @TheCardCheat!  I was using `parent_app.app_name` and getting nowhere.

Answer (score 9):

Your app must contain a `models.py` file (even emtpy).

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/bsTZEmxgDJM/wH0p3xinBWIJ

Answer (score 3):

Just to mention another possible reason:

In my Django app i added the correct migrations and installed the app with pip and got the same error.

What i was missing is a correct MANIFEST.in file
Also the parameter `include_package_data` in setup() from the setup.py file was not set to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the following:

1. Confirm that 'app_name.apps.AppNameConfig' is added to the list of installed apps.
2. Double-check the project's database configuration in the `settings.py` file.
3. Make sure that each application includes a directory named `migrations`, and within that directory, there is a file named `__init__.py`.